# Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Configuration.dll gets exceptioncode 0xc0000409 when executing SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

when executing an SSIS package on a virtual machine set up as following:

Windows Server 2016 v 1607 (OS Build 14393.2248)
SQL Server 2016 Enterprise with Service Pack 1 v13.0.4466.4
Integration Services v13.0.4001

I get the following exception:

```
Faulting application name: dtexecui.exe, version: 13.0.1601.5, time stamp: 0x572453d7
Faulting module name: Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Configuration.dll, 
version: 2015.130.1601.5, 
time stamp: 0x57244e3d
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000dec7
Faulting process id: 0xc20
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4b3d557c938d3
```

followed by:

```
Fault bucket 116384339059, type 5
Event Name: BEX
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
```

Problem signature:

```
P1: dtexecui.exe
P2: 13.0.1601.5
P3: 572453d7
P4: Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Configuration.dll
P5: 2015.130.1601.5
P6: 57244e3d
P7: 0000dec7
P8: c0000409
P9: 00000002
P10:
```

I have attempted to reinstall SSIS services, check for various permissions for the running accounts, reinstalled the SSIS package with more logging but I can't seem to get any closer to a fix.

Comment: `0xc0000409`, `STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`, "The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application." Definitely not the usual stuff. Is your .NET Framework installation up to date (mostly, not .NET 4.6 with its buggy JIT compiler)? Any freaky anti-malware software installed that could do bad things to running code? Is upgrading an option? (The latest build of SQL Server 2016 is SP2 CU5). Does it happen with *all* SSIS packages (try a dummy, empty one) or just one particular package that may load funky DLLs?

Comment: Currently installed:
.NET Framework 4.6.1586.0

I tried slimming down the SSIS package to only execute one sp and it still crashed with the same error after recompiling the package.

I can ask the IT department if upgrading is an option but it's not something I can attempt right now.

What I can say is that it works on another installation of the same version.

Comment: Then you're probably out of luck, short of reinstalling/updating the OS (to get rid of errant updates/settings), or using a standalone SSIS instance on a separate machine. There's *a* difference between the working and non-working setups, but if it's one that causes a buffer overrun in one case and not another, tracking it down is going to be a nightmare. As in a "take a memory dump on both machines and have a developer who knows WinDbg compare them" kind of nightmare. (Even if you find the cause this way, you usually still don't have a solution.)

Comment: Received an OK to update the OS and SQL Server on monday, I'll get back with results from that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Updating the OS, .NET Framework, SQL Server and SSMS did not help. So I think we will have to try creating a separate server for SSIS.

Thanks for the help @JeroenMostert